# Azure Dev Ops replace function not working on \\

Tags: azure-devops

I have a template like

```
parameters:
  Server: ''

steps:
- powershell: echo "${{ parameters.Server }}"
- powershell: echo "${{ replace(parameters.Server, '\\', '\') }}"
- powershell: echo "${{ replace(parameters.Server, '\\\\', '\') }}"
- powershell: echo "${{ replace(parameters.Server, '\\\\', '\\') }}"
- powershell: echo "${{ replace(parameters.Server, '\', '\\') }}"
- powershell: echo "${{ replace(parameters.Server, 'parameters', 'xxx') }}"
```

and use it like

```
- template: 'path'
  parameters:
    Server: $(Server.Variable)
```

where the variable `Server.Variable` is defined on the stage level as `host\\path`

but the output is

```
host\\path
host\\path
host\\path
host\\path
host\\path
host\\path
```

so what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My solution now is to create a new variable at the job level which is defined using a runtime expression and give the changed variable into the template

```
jobs:
- job:
  variables:
    Changed.Server.Variable: $[ replace(variables['Server.Variable'], '\\', '\') ]
  steps:
    ...
    - template: 'path'
      parameters:
        Server: $(Changed.Server.Variable)
```

but I would like a solution more where we can change the value in the template, but I don't know how.